# Could a unique variable such as invoice_id be used as a target variable?

Tags: machine-learning

I am trying to create a machine learning algorithm that will match invoice numbers with un-applied accounts receivable receipts.

un-applied receipts are just receipts that do not match the details we have in our database such as the amount.

My problem is that I do not know what the target variable should be. Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a problem for machine learning. What makes you think that ML is the correct tool for this? Also, if you can share a bit more details about your data, that would be helpful!

Comment: I think ML would be the correct tool for this because there are simply too many variables that come into play for it to be a simple program that uses a bunch of if statements. There is a lot of discretion that goes into matching these invoices to unapplied amounts. Here are some of the details of the data I have: INVOICE_ID, INVOICE_AMOUNT, DUE_DATE, CREATION_DATE, CUSTOMER_ID, AMOUNT_APPLIED, CREATED_BY. When an amount goes unapplied it does not have some of the associated details such as invoice_id. However, I could be wrong on this being a use case for machine learning

Comment: The data I will be using is current unapplied recipt data and manually fixed data which has the correct invoice_id associated.